# Corda bridge not able to connect to peer node using proxy

Tags: blockchain, corda, corda-flow, corda-dlt

I have configured proxyConfig in firewall.conf in my corda firewall component-bridge to connect via HTTP CONNECT.
when a flow is invoked, in logs of bridge I see that "remoteAddress" of the peer node is mentioned as IP of proxy server and not the p2p address of the peer node., see below log:

```
[INFO ] 2023-06-20T05:45:48,246Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] netty.AMQPChannelHandler. - New client connection 2c59e6f0 from proxy.mylocalgroup.net/IP.OF.PROXY.SERVER:PORT to /IP.OF.ARTEMIS.SERVER:PORT {allowedRemoteLegalNames=O=BNO, L=London, C=GB, localCert=null, remoteAddress=proxy.mylocalgroup.net/IP.OF.PROXY.SERVER:PORT, remoteCert=null, serverMode=false}
[WARN ] 2023-06-20T05:45:48,249Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] netty.AMQPChannelHandler. - failure when writing TLS control frames {allowedRemoteLegalNames=O=BNO, L=London, C=GB, localCert=null, remoteAddress=proxy.mylocalgroup.net/IP.OF.PROXY.SERVER:PORT, remoteCert=null, serverMode=false}
```

is this the expected behaviour when bridge is setup behind proxy?
also when I setup the nodes in single VM(along with corda firewall components) I see p2p address of the peer node in "remoteAddress"., which I believe makes more sense.
please provide feedback.